# os.walk renaming folders which contain a '.'

Tags: python, os.walk

I use the following code to replace file/folder names in a directory.

```
old = abc
new = def

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
    for name in files:
        if old in name:
            file_path = os.path.join(path, name)
            new_name = os.path.join(path, name.replace(old, new))
            os.rename(file_path, new_name)
```

This works, however, I have one folder named `abc.files` os.walk does not see this folder, how do I fix the code so it changes `abc.files` to `def.files` ?

Comment: If `abc.files` is a subdir, then it will be in the `subdirs` list, not the `files` list.  You're only iterating over `files`.

Comment: Also, `new = def` is an error.  Did you mean `new = "def"`?

Comment: If you rename directories while walking, you should use `topdown=False` so it will walk into the subdirectory before it renames it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, you're only renaming files, not subdirectories, because you're not looping over the `subdirs` list. Try this:

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(folder_path, topdown=False):
    for name in files + subdirs:
        if old in name:
            file_path = os.path.join(path, name)
            new_name = os.path.join(path, name.replace(old, new))
            os.rename(file_path, new_name)
```

`topdown = False` ensures that it will walk into a subdirectory before it's renamed.

Comment: you help me understand better about `os.walk()`; `for name in filter(lambda x: x and old in x, files + subdirs)` so u no need to `if old in name`

Comment: They're equivalent, but I think most people find the `if` statement easier to read.